# How to add a dynamic value in settings.py Django

Tags: python, django

I want to maintain a variable `TOKEN` in my `settings.py` of my django project, and it changed with time.

The `token` saved at db like:

```
class FbBmToken(models.Model):
    manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    effective = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fb_bm_token'
```

And I want use it in my django project anywhere by

```
from django.conf import settings


token = settings.TOKEN
```

How can I make this happen?

Greate thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a method to get the latest token from your database.
you should try this :

```
def get_latest_token():
   token = FbBmToken.objects.latest('id')
   token.refresh_from_db()
   return token
```

Now, you can directly call this method whenever you want to get the latest updated token. I hope this would work for you.

Comment: If this answer is usefull to you then please make sure to upvote it. 